# Creating and Archive of an XCode 5 project seems to uninitalize the local git repo

Tags: ios, xcode, git, github

Today I noticed that when I created an Archive in XCode 5 and exported the IPA, the next time I tried to push my local branch to GitHub XCode told me my local branch did not seem to be a git repository.  All I had to do was navigate to the folder  through Terminal that contains the project and do a git init command and poof, it worked.  I noticed this as I was creating multiple archives in a row (created one, added to TestFlightApp, tested, made some changes, created a new archive etc...).  On every iteration I had to do the git init command to be able to push new changes to the remote repo.  Can someone explain why this might be?

Comment: If you disable source control completely in preferences, does it stop messing things up?

Comment: Not sure, I am afraid to do that :-)  I am pretty far along in this project and if something got too jacked up I would seriously consider jabbing myself in the eye with a toothpick...

Comment: Well, you have a building version in source control, and you can always delete Xcode and reinstall it.  But it's up to you.  That's all I can think of to try: change the pref or re-install.  Others may have ideas.